# Search for multiple strings in many text files, count hits on combinations

Tags: regex, bash, perl, shell, data-structures

I'm struggling to automate a reporting exercise, and would appreciate some pointers or advice please.

I have several hundred thousand small (<5kb) text files. Each contains a few variables, and I need to count the number of files that match each combination of variables.

Each file contains a device number, such as /001/ /002/.../006/.

Each file also contains a date string, such as 01.10.14 (dd.mm.yy)

Some files contain a 'status' string which is always "Not Settled"

I need a way to trawl through each file on a Linux system (spread across several subdirectories), and produce a report file that counts 'per device' how many files include each date stamp (6 month range) and for each of those dates, how many contain the status string.

The report might look like this:
device, date, total count of files
device, date, total "not settled" count

e.g.

```
/001/, 01.12.14, 356
/001/, 01.12.14, 12
/001/, 02.12.14, 209
/001/, 02.12.14, 8 
/002/, 01.12.14, 209
/002/, 01.12.14, 7
```

etc etc

In other words:

```
Foreach /device/
Foreach <date>
count total matching files - write number to file
count toal matching 'not settled' files - write number to file
```

Each string to match could appear anywhere in the file.

I tried using grep piped to a second (and third) grep commands, but I'd like to automate this and loop through the variables (6 devices, about 180 dates, 2 status strings) . I suspect Perl and Bash is the answer, but I'm out of my depth.

Please can anyone recommend an approach to this?

Edit: Some sample data as mentioned in the comments. The information is basically receipt data from tills - as would be sent to a printer. Here's a sample (identifying bits stripped out).

```
c0!                       SUBTOTAL     11.37   
c0!   ! T O T A L      11.37! 
c0!   19 ITEMS                                 
c0!   C a s h             ?            11.37   
vu p022c0!                                            
c0!   NET TOTAL           VAT  A       10.87   
c0!   VAT                 00.0%         0.00   
c0!   NET TOTAL           VAT  B        0.42   
c0!   VAT                 20.0%         0.08   
c0!  *4300 772/080/003/132 08.01.15 11:18 A-00 

      Contents = Not Settled
```

In the case above, I'd be looking for /003/ , 08.01.15, and "Not Settled"

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example of a source file? But this sounds pretty straightfoward using perl and a hash.

Comment: Agreed, perl can handle it. But you can't parse something unless you know what it looks like.

Comment: Thanks. I've added a snippet of sample data to the original question.

Comment: Thank you Shellter for sorting my formatting out - I struggled with that!

Answer (score 1):

First, read everything into an SQLite database, then run queries against it to your heart's content. Putting the data in an SQL database is going to save you time if you need to tweak anything. Besides, even simple SQL can tackle this kind of thing if you have the right tables set up.

Comment: ++ read it all into an SQLIte database ... but use perl ;-)  http://perlmaven.com/simple-database-access-using-perl-dbi-and-sql

Answer (score 1):

First of all I agree with @Sinan :-)

The following might work as hack to make a hash out of your file data.

```
# report.pl
use strict;
use warnings;    
use Data::Dumper;

my %report;
my ($date, $device) ;

while (<>) {

 next unless m/^ .* 
    (?<device>\/00[1-3]\/) .* 
    (?<date>\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}) 
    .*$/x ; 

  ($date, $device,) = ($+{date}, $+{device});

  $_ = <> unless eof;

  if (/Contents/) { 
     $report{$date}{$device}{"u_count"}++ ;
  } 
  else {
     $report{$date}{$device}{"count"}++ ; 
  }
}

print Dumper(\%report)
```

This seems to work with a collection of data files in the format shown below (since you don't say or show where the `Contents = Not Settled` appears, I assume it is *either* part of the last line along with the device ID *or* in a separate and final line for each file).

**Explanation**:

- The script reads the STDIN of all the files passed as a glob in `while(<>){}` loop. First, `next unless m/ ...` skips forward lines of input until it matches the line with device and date information.
- Next, the match then uses [named capture groups](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Capture-groups) (`?<device> ?<date>` to hold the values of the patterns it finds and places those values in corresponding variables (`($date, $device,) = ($+{date}, $+{device});`). These could simply be `$1` and `$2` but naming keeps me organized here.
- Then, in case there is another line to read `$_ = <> unless eof;` reads it and tries the final set of conditional matches in order to add to `$counts` and `$u_counts`.

**Data file format:**

`file1.data`

```
c0! SUBTOTAL 11.37
c0! ! T O T A L 11.37! c0! 19 ITEMS
c0! C a s h ? 11.37
vu p022c0!
c0! NET TOTAL VAT A 10.87
c0! VAT 00.0% 0.00
c0! NET TOTAL VAT B 0.42
c0! VAT 20.0% 0.08
c0! *4300 772/080/003/132 08.01.15 11:18 A-00
```

`file2.data`

```
c0! SUBTOTAL 11.37
c0! ! T O T A L 11.37! c0! 19 ITEMS
c0! C a s h ? 11.37
vu p022c0!
c0! NET TOTAL VAT A 10.87
c0! VAT 00.0% 0.00
c0! NET TOTAL VAT B 0.42
c0! VAT 20.0% 0.08
c0! *4300 772/080/002/132 08.01.15 11:18 A-00 
Contents = Not Settled
```

(a set of files for testing are listed here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=7ALU80fE).

`perl report.pl file*.data`

[`Data::Dumper`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper) **Output**:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '08.01.15' => {
                          '/002/' => {
                                       'u_count' => 4
                                     },
                          '/003/' => {
                                       'count' => 1
                                     }
                        },
          '08.12.15' => {
                          '/003/' => {
                                       'count' => 1
                                     }
                        }
        };
```

From that you can make a report by iterating through the hash with `keys()` (the date) and retrieving the inner hash and count values per machine. Really it would be a good idea to have some tests to make sure everything works as expected - that or just do as @sinan_Ünür suggests: use SQLite!

**NB**: this code was not extensively tested :-)

Comment: Thanks - that's really appreciated. I haven't had chance to give it a try yet, but I'll do so as soon as I can. It's going to take me a while to understand what's going on in the code though!

Comment: @GlennBooth OK I added some explanatory comments to my code  ... hope it works with your data!  A more thorough explanation for `$_ = <> unless eof;` (or an alternative) might improve things (I will think about this a bit more). Hope it helps.